# backgroundworker gives a cross-thread exception when ProgressChanged?

Tags: c#, winforms, exception, backgroundworker, multithreading

i have file transfer application (Server-Client) TCP [.net 4]
why is backgroundworker gives me an exception in (backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged)

The client send command that has a **destination path** (where file should saved into) and the **size of file** to the Server to start receiving that file .. so once the server takes that command .. it will call :

```
fileTransfer1.Receive(destPath, fileSize);
```

this method run in its own thread in form1.cs :

```
private void Job(object o)
    {

        Socket client = (Socket)o;
        NetworkStream stream = new NetworkStream(client);
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream);

        string cmd = null;

        while ((cmd = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            string[] command = cmd.Split('<');
            switch (command[0])
            {
               case "receive":
                            fileTransfer1.Receive(command[1], Convert.ToInt64(command[2]));
                            break;
                            default:
                            break;
            }
        }
```

**fileTransfer1 (userControl)** :

```
    public void Receive(string destPath, long fileSize)
    {
            List<object> job = new List<object>();
            job.Add(destPath);
            job.Add(fileSize);
            backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync(job);
    }

    long sum = 0;
    long fileSize = 0;   //this will equal the size of the file later.
    private void ReceiveFile(string destPath, long fileSize)
    {
        using (fs = new FileStream(destPath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
        {
            try
            {
                int count = 0;
                data = new byte[packetSize];
                while (sum < fileSize)
                {
                    count = network.Read(data, 0, packetSize);
                    fs.Write(data, 0, count);
                    sum += count;
                    backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress((int)((sum * 100) / fileSize));
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                CloseTransfer();
            }
        }
    }
```

here's backgroundworker method :

```
    private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
         List<object> job = (List<object>)e.Argument;
         string destPath = (string)job[1];
         long fileSize = (long)job[2];
         ReceiveFile(destPath, fileSize);
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        progressBarFile.Position = e.ProgressPercentage;
        progressBarFile.Text = progressBarFile.Position.ToString() + "%";
  /*here*/  labelRemaining.Text = CnvrtUnit(fileSize - sum);  
    }
```

my problem that i got an exception **(Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'labelRemaining' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.)**
that references to this line:

```
 labelRemaining.Text = CnvrtUnit(fileSize - sum);
```

i know about that exception and i know that i have to use (delegate/invoke) thing .. but.. i know that backgroundworker meant for this .. plus .. i have the same code but The server here Send a file to the client .. and it doesn't give that exception .. it works fine and the form shows me the details as it should be.
**So why do i get this exception just when i receive a file ??**
 note : receive method works fine.

Comment: Which form is hosting the BackgroundWorker?  Is there a "download progress" popup, like what Chrome or IE shows?

Comment: @ChrisShain nope its a userControl in that main form .. that receives the file and shows the receiving progress.

Comment: n/m that wouldn't matter in this exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i've figured that out

since my command receiver method **Void Job(object o)** is running under a thread .. so this:

```
case "receive":
           fileTransfer1.Receive(command[1], Convert.ToInt64(command[2]));
           break;
```

also runs in the same thread .. that means the rest of the code also runs in that thread ..
so i just changed this line to this:

```
case "receive":
       Action a = () => fileTransfer1.Receive(command[2], Convert.ToInt64(command[3])); 
       Invoke(a);
       break;
```

now UI-Thread will be notified to run the rest of the receiving code .. which solved my problem.

Answer (score 2):

You are getting that error because `backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged()` is running on a thread different from the thread that created the `labelRemaining` control.   Assuming you created the `labelRemaining` control on the main UI thread, you need to either:

- Execute `backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync(job)` from the main thread.

  **or**
- Inside `backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged`, use the Dispatcher to execute the change to your `labelRemaining` object on the main thread as [described here](http://elegantcode.com/2009/07/03/wpf-multithreading-using-the-backgroundworker-and-reporting-the-progress-to-the-ui/)

Update: 
I see you are using winforms and not WPF.  Rather than using the Dispatcher this should work for you: [How to update the GUI from another thread in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/661561/how-to-update-gui-from-another-thread-in-c)

Comment: i think you might be right .. because at receiving case .. the method that receives commands from the client is running in a thread so then it calls backgroundworker.runasync() in the same thread that receives the commands.. is that's why i get this exception ?

Comment: I am pretty sure that is why.  Otherwise you would not be getting that exception from the BackgroundWorker.

Comment: @MurHafSoz That's great, if my response helped you then please mark it as such.  Thanks.

Comment: you right.. you remind me that i am really running job method in a thread that helped me about how to think to solve the problem.. but i should let the answer to be clear for other people who has the same issue.. im gonna mark my answer.